# How to join a column to another column based on two conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I am at a bit of a loss why this is not working/updating. I have a 'sites' table and a 'visit' table. The 'sites' table contains all the unique 'sites' with in the DB and the 'visit' table contains all the unique visits to all the sites.

Site

| site_id | region | site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a |
| 2 | a | b |
| 3 | b | a |
| 4 | b | b |

Visit

| visit_id | region | site | date | site_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a | 1 |  |
| 2 | a | b | 2 |  |
| 3 | b | a | 3 |  |
| 4 | b | b | 2 |  |
| 5 | c | a | 3 |  |
| 6 | c | b | 1 |  |
| 7 | d | a | 2 |  |
| 8 | d | b | 2 |  |

When region and site equal each other I want the site_id to populate in the 'visit' table. Here is what I have tried. It does not throw and error but nothing populates in the visit.site_id.

```
update visit a 
set site_id = 
    (select s.site_id
    from site s
    where (s.region, s.site)  = (a.region, a.site));
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: There is no error. It runs but nothing populates @FarshidShekari

Comment: If you mean refreshing and disconnecting from DB then yes @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: try `where s.region = a.region and s.site = a.site`

Comment: region and site are both text. You can join on text exact matches of text correct? and @Andrew same result as above

Comment: This is a schema mistake. A well-designed `visit` table would **ONLY** have `id`, `site_id`, and `date` columns, and not repeat the region and site columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your way has a problem and if even it works, it does not work correctly because if there are the same tuples in both tables your query will update all of them.

```
update visit a 
set site_id = 
    (select s.site_id
    from sites s
    where (s.region, s.site)  = (a.region, a.site) and a.region = a.site);
```

rewriting in another way:

```
update visit a 
set site_id = 
    (select s.site_id
    from sites s
    where  s.region = a.region and s.site = a.site and a.region = a.site);
```

Here's the result(my PostgreSQL version is 13):
[image]

Comment: Your code still does not populate my column. It must be something on my end. Once I create the empty column, "site_id" I should refresh and disconnect from the DB. Is there anything else I should do before running that code chunk?

Comment: @Jake I didn't do any special things, first, check your data is the same as reported here(if there's no data in return in your subquery nothing will be updated), another thing you can also use the PostgreSQL shell for running your query. also, you can try with this =>>  begin your_code_here; commit; end;

Comment: Thank you for all the help. After closing it down and re-opening this morning the strings in the columns were slightly different. Now working properly.